# How can I reload a Geolocation Javascript every minute?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, timer, geolocation

I have made a prototype with Geolocation JavaScript and in the browser it shows a Map with several markers and a marker with your current location. At this time i would like make my website so that it automatically reloads so you can see your new location (if you move). Right now the Javascript is very easy. It is a basis Google Maps API combined with a Geolocation API.

Is there anyone who know how I can apply a "timer" so my website reloads every few minutes?

Comment: you can use jquery timer plugin. http://jquerytimer.com/

Comment: [`Geolocation.watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) ?

Answer (score 0):

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) is used to run a piece of code every x milliseconds.

Just wrap the code you want to run every second in a function called runFunction.

Like this:

```
var time=setInterval(runFunction,1000);
```

And to stop it, you can run:

```
clearInterval(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

The if your map function is map
**1sec = 1000**

```
function map(){
.......
}
setInterval(map(), 60000);
```